# Bootstrap: align 'card's horizontally as a single row

Tags: css, django, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, django-templates

i am rendering the 4 items in a row through a for loop , the problem is that in the first line it renders 4 items but the rest of the items that come in the loop are rendered in separate line.

**code**

```
<div class="card-group">

    {% for item in wt %}

          <div class="card my-3 text-white bg-dark mb-3" style="width: 18rem;">

            <img src="/media/{{item.thumbnail}}" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">{{item.product_name}}</h5>
              <p class="card-text">{{item.thumbnail_desc}}</p>

              <a href="blog_detail/{{item.post_id}}" class="btn btn-primary">View Product</a>


            </div>
          </div>

    {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:4 %}
    </div>
    {% endif %}

   {% endfor %}
```

here i am using bootstrap and django framework... i also used "row" class but it also doesnt work very well

Comment: Can you reform your question?

Comment: whats not clear ?

Comment: You want each item in a single row right ?

Comment: {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:4 %}
    </div>
    {% endif %}  ... i want to print 4 items in one row , so it is printing 4 in first row but not in all

Comment: no i want 4 items in single row

Answer (score 0):

It should automatically do 4 to a row without having to add extra code:

```
    {% for item in wt %}

          <div class="card my-3 text-white bg-dark mb-3" style="width: 18rem;">

            <img src="/media/{{item.thumbnail}}" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">{{item.product_name}}</h5>
              <p class="card-text">{{item.thumbnail_desc}}</p>

              <a href="blog_detail/{{item.post_id}}" class="btn btn-primary">View Product</a>


            </div>
          </div> 
   {% endfor %}
```

If not, try using class "col-md-3" instead of "my-3".

Let me know if this does the trick.

Comment: i posted the correct answer see the comment , it was the size of cards that was creating the problem... my-3 adds vertical spacing while col-md-3 help in centering the content

Answer (score 0):

it worked by changing size of the card and also adding forloop's counter... the main problem was the size of the card , it was not fitting in the container

```
<h2 class="my-4 text-white bg-dark">New Arrivals</h2>
            <div class="row">
         {% for item in wt %}

          <div class="card text-white bg-dark mb-3" style="width: 10rem;">

            <img src="/media/{{item.thumbnail}}" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">{{item.product_name}}</h5>
              <p class="card-text">{{item.thumbnail_desc}}</p>

              <a href="detail/{{item.post_id}}" class="btn btn-primary">View Product</a>


            </div>
          </div>
                 {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:4 %}
    </div>
        <div class="row">
    {% endif %}

   {% endfor %}

        </div>
```